# Techniques for Evaluating the Laplace Transform of an Exponential R.V. with Trigonometric Coefficients

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, laplace-transform, exponential-distribution, summation-method

What techniques that have been used to evaluate a tricky integral?

$$
\mathcal{L}G_{j,k}(\tau) 
= 
    \int_0^{\infty} G_{j,k}(\tau) e^{-\tau\beta} d\tau
$$
which apparently evaluates to,
$$
    \sum_{\mu=0}^j\sum_{\nu=0}^k
    \frac{
          \binom{j}{\mu}\binom{k}{\nu}
          \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{j+k}(-1)^{\frac{k}{2}+\nu}B
         }{
         (\beta\bar{\tau} +1)^2 + (\omega\bar{\tau})^2 (j+k-2 \mu -2 \nu )^2
         }
\quad
\text{where}\ 
B = \cases{
       \beta\bar{\tau} +1 & \text{if}\ \frac{1}{2}k \in \mathbb{N}\\
       (j+k-2\mu - 2\nu)\omega\bar{\tau} & \text{if}\ \frac{1}{2}k \notin \mathbb{N}
      }
$$

The integral is a Laplace transform of the function,
$$
G_{j,k}(\tau) = re^{-r\tau} \cos ^j(\tau  \omega ) \sin ^k(\tau  \omega )
$$

**Definitions**

- $\tau$ is an exponentially distributed random variable: $P(\tau) = re^{-r\tau}$
- $\bar{\tau}$ is the average value of $\tau$
- The rate paramter, $r$, is the inverse of the average value of $\tau$ as $r = 1/\bar{\tau}$
- $\omega$ is a constant
- $j,k \in \mathbb{N}$ (assume the convention $0 \in \mathbb{N}$)

In the paper, only $(j,k) \in \{(0,0), (1,1), (2,0), (0,2)\}$ are actually used so it is possible that the Transform has only been defined in this domain. This is not explicitly indicated, however, so I assume it is general.

**Current Progress**

- I can easily solve for the restricted domain $(j,k) \in \{(0,0), (1,1), (2,0), (0,2)\}$ and piece together the more general form in a backwards form.
- The only method I currently know of is to solve in an iterative format and collect terms

Comment: The equations are (41) and (43) on pages 22 and 23 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-lat/0008020v1.pdf). I should also point out that the case of $G_{1,1}$ seems to be a factor of $\mathbb{i}$ different to the supposed answer

Comment: I think the equation in the question comes from expressing trigonometric function in exponential form by Euler's formula $e^{i\phi}=\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Actually, that's the way I perform the integrals when solving for the restricted domain and backwards engineering the solution. However, it doesn't help with the general form

Comment: Why not? I feel it just works well.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken this still requires an iterative approach for all $i,j$ values which is what I have already done. The binomial coefficients suggest to me that there might be a more general method at work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way I mentioned in the comments works well.
$$\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty G_{j,k}(\tau)e^{-\tau\beta}d\tau\\
= & \int_0^\infty re^{-(\beta+r)\tau}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{j+k}(e^{i\omega\tau}+e^{-i\omega\tau})^j (e^{i\omega\tau}-e^{-i\omega\tau})^k (-i)^k\\
= & \int_0^\infty re^{-(\beta+r)\tau}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{j+k}(-i)^k \sum_{\mu=0}^j\sum_{\nu=0}^k (-1)^\nu e^{i\omega(2\mu+2\nu-j-k)\tau}d\tau\\
= & r\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{j+k}(-i)^k  \sum_{\mu=0}^j\sum_{\nu=0}^k (-1)^\nu \int_0^\infty e^{(i\omega(2\mu+2\nu-j-k)-(\beta+r))\tau}d\tau\\
= & r\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{j+k}(-i)^k \sum_{\mu=0}^j\sum_{\nu=0}^k\frac{(-1)^\nu}{i\omega(2\mu+2\nu-j-k)-(\beta+r)}
\end{align}$$
Which easily simplifies to the given equation.

Comment: great answer, I had completely forgotten about the existence of the binomial expansion !